# How to use a select statement inside a function?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to build a function that returns a value from a table

```
    create or replace 
FUNCTION TO_LOCAL_CURRENCY 
(
  CURR IN VARCHAR2  
, VAL IN VARCHAR2  
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
BEGIN

  RETURN (select EXRATE 
  from exchangerates 
  where CURR = 'EUR' ) * VAL;
END TO_LOCAL_CURRENCY;
```

Basically I feed in a currency and value and it looks up the exchange rate from the table exchangerates and multiplies the EXRATE by VAL and returns the result.

I get the following error

```
Error(9,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT` the result `INTO` a local variable, and return that:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION TO_LOCAL_CURRENCY 
(
  CURR IN VARCHAR2  
, VAL IN VARCHAR2  
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
  EXCHANGE_RATE NUMBER;
BEGIN

  select EXRATE 
  into EXCHANGE_RATE 
  from exchangerates 
  where CURR = 'EUR';

  return EXCHANGE_RATE * VAL;

END TO_LOCAL_CURRENCY;
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error. Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; not null range default character The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

Comment: Sorry, seems I forgot a semicolon. Is it working now?